# Magento 2 custom API Implementation

Tags: magento2, magento2-api

I am overriding the default Magento2 model file `Product.php` in my custom module and for my custom API creation. In my custom API call data is coming from default Magento2 `Product.php` file rather than my custom module file.
My di.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Test\Test\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="Test\Test\Model\ProductRepository"/>
    <preference for="Test\Test\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="Test\Test\Model\Product"/>
    <preference for="Test\Test\Api\Data\ProductInterface" type="Test\Test\Model\Product"/>
</config>
```

Default Product.php file using with name space changes in my custom module

Comment: Post the code of di.xml file and your product.php which you have overrides

Comment: are you need custom rest api or soap api?

Comment: custom REST API